# Getting Peace of Westphalia in League War while not war leader?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm playing EU4 on latest patch (Rule Britannia) as GB, I went Anglican religion. I want to become Emperor of the HRE and to do that I need to have neither Catholic nor Protestant win the religious war - have the war end without either side demanding religious supremacy.
Naturally I joined the league war against the emperor, but I'm not the leader since I'm not protestant.

What can I do to steer the war towards Peace of Westphalia?

Answer (score 1):

Your natural reaction was indeed the wrong one in this case.

To get the peace of westphalia the religous league war must either end with a peace treaty not specifying supremacy (e.g. by completely exhausting both war leaders) or go on for a very long time (25-30 years) to end automatically.

To ensure this as an outsider, you should have stayed neutral, watched the league war and intervene for the losing side, when necessary to create a balance of power until the war ends. Or, if you are strong enough, declare war on both leagues and conquer them to force the leaders to end the league war inconclusively.

In your current situation, your only hope is for the catholic side to be naturally stronger, so you can only intervene, when necessary to prevent the protestants from losing. If the protestants are naturally stronger, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You can not join a league after the war has been declared, tho.

Comment: @Polygnome I'm not tlaking about joining a league, I mean simply attacking the factions who are winning the league war

Comment: The most effective way of ensuring a draw in the league war is choosing a side, then doing nothing. If you are strong, and the leader declares because he thinks he is strong enough, then doing nothing means it will be a draw. If the war goes badly, you can still balance it by participating just enough.b Especially as england, you can easily stay out of the war by staying n your own island. the Ai rarely sends troops there, and if they do, you sink em with your navy.

Comment: @Polygnome If your side is strong enough to win without you, this plan horribly backfires.

Comment: Yes, but intervening as outsider is also problematic, since you do not necessarily have CBs against the major players, and No CB wars mean a shit ton of AE, especially in the HRE, not to mention the stab hits. And all that AE will bite you in the ass - goal is to become emperor after all, which means you need good relations to the electors.

Comment: @Polygnome Securing CBs against the league leaders shouldn't be too difficult. For the catholic side, you merely need a CB against any non-protestant league HRE nation, the emperor will defend it. So, the only challenge is to get a CB vs the leader of the protestant league, which might be easy or hard depending on who it is. This differs from game to game. In any case, risking a no CB war against the protestant league is still preferable to being unable to stop your league from winning the war.

Comment: Emperor will defend it, but the electors will not necessarily follow, especially when they are already in another war. And sometimes France or Ottomans get involved, too, which will obviously not help the emperor. I've successfully gotten a draw in the league wars three or four times just by doing nothing, its just a lot less hassle. If you are strong enough, the league leader will declare, and you not participating will have the wanted effect. if you are not strong enough, you'll have a hard time fighting the emperor or other big players like Kebab or France on your own, anyways.